# Get all values for an Enum constant in Java? (Is there a built-in method to do that or do I need to write my own getters?)

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum like the following:

```
public enum Foo {

   BAR("v1", "v2", "v3"),
   BAZ("x1", "x2", "x3"),
   // ...

   // version a
   private String[] vals;
   private Foo(String... vals) {
      this.vals = vals;
   }

   // version b
   private String v1, v2, v3;
   private Foo(String v1, String v2, String v3) {
      this.v1 = v1;
      this.v2 = v2;
      this.v3 = v3;
   }

}
```

How do I get a List of "v1", "v2", "v3" back when I know I have a Foo.BAR?
Do I have to write my own getters, or is there something built into Enum, much like values() (but for the actual values)?

Comment: There is no built-in method of doing that, those fields are just like fields for any other class. What exactly do you want to do? It seems like an enum *might* be the wrong choice here (or it might not, but we don't have enough information to judge that).

Comment: if you use version A, then you just have to add `public String[] getValues() { return vals; }`

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own getter(s) for custom properties, etc.  For your "version A" example, you could do

```
public String[] getValues() {
  return vals;
}
```

(though you probably would want to return a copy of values, rather than the array itself.)

Comment: There wasn't an automated way of cloning objects in Java, though, was there?

Comment: There's not a general-purpose way of doing so; if you're storing an array, though, you can use java.util.Arrays.copyOf() to copy your array.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if your v1,v2,v3 are some random unrelated values, i think is better to go with version b, and create separate getter for each one

if from other hand they are related, then you could return copy of your array or have single getter like this one

```
String getValue(int index){
return vals[index-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write/ (or with an IDE generate) the getters yourself.